# To show u and v form orthogonal basis for $R^2$ wrt inner product <u,v>=$2u_1v_1+u_1v_2+u_2v_1+5u_2v_2$ and find orthonormal basis. u=(-2,1), v=(1,1)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a two part question of which I have a semi-correct answer and can't figure out where I've gone wrong.

Let **u**=(-2,1) and **v**=(1,1)

*i) Show **u** and **v** form an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R^2}$ wrt inner product 
<**u**,**v**>=$2u_1v_1+u_1v_2+u_2v_1+5u_2v_2$. Use this basis to find an orthonormal basis by normalizing each vector.*

First I showed **u** and **v** formed a basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$ by row reduction to get 2x2 identity matrix.

Second I showed **u** and **v** are orthogonal using the given inner product space and found that <**u**,**v**>=0

Third I normalised each vector to get ||**u**||=3 and ||**v**||=3 to give unit vectors for **u** to be **a**=(-2/3,1/3) and **v** to be **b**=(1/3,1/3).

*ii) Express vector **w**=(1/3,4/3) as a linear combination of the orthonormal basis vectors obtained in part i.*

To find linear combination of the two vectors I let **w**=$c_1$**a**+$c_2$**b** then solved to get $c_1=1$ and $c_2=3$ . These coefficients aren't correct because when I check and sub values in I get **w**=$c_1$**a**+$c_2$**b**=(-2/3,1)+3(1/3,1/3)=(1/3,2)
but the answer should be **w**=(1/3,4/3) after substituting.

I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: No need to solve $c_1,c_2$ from any equation. You have an orthonormal basis, so
$$c_1=\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{a}\rangle=1,\quad c_2=\langle\mathbf{u},\mathbf{b}\rangle=3.$$

Comment: Can you please review editied post? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you just copied $b$ wrong in your very last calculation to check your work.

Answer (score 0):

After you normalize **u** you should have $a = (-2/3, 1/3)$

Comment: Sorry, that is what I have. I made I typo.

Comment: @Angie01: So there is no longer any mystery, right?